# Open a popup when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I have made a popup form in Flodesk and have installed the following Javascript Snippet before the closing head tag of my website.

```
<script>
  (function(w, d, t, h, s, n) {
    w.FlodeskObject = n;
    var fn = function() {
      (w[n].q = w[n].q || []).push(arguments);
    };
    w[n] = w[n] || fn;
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    var v = '?v=' + Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (120 * 1000)) * 60;
    var sm = d.createElement(t);
    sm.async = true;
    sm.type = 'module';
    sm.src = h + s + '.mjs' + v;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(sm, f);
    var sn = d.createElement(t);
    sn.async = true;
    sn.noModule = true;
    sn.src = h + s + '.js' + v;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(sn, f);
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://assets.flodesk.com', '/universal', 'fd');
</script>
<script>
  window.fd('form', {
    formId: '615edb53f88d548e68f5c863'
  });
</script>
```

Currently, my popup form automatically opens when the page loads. I would instead like it to open when a button is clicked. Is there any way I can do this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like

```js
window.fd('form', {
    formId: '615edb53f88d548e68f5c863'
  });
```

opens the modal, so you could call it with a function when a button is clicked. Example:

```html
<script>
  (function(w, d, t, h, s, n) {
    w.FlodeskObject = n;
    var fn = function() {
      (w[n].q = w[n].q || []).push(arguments);
    };
    w[n] = w[n] || fn;
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    var v = '?v=' + Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / (120 * 1000)) * 60;
    var sm = d.createElement(t);
    sm.async = true;
    sm.type = 'module';
    sm.src = h + s + '.mjs' + v;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(sm, f);
    var sn = d.createElement(t);
    sn.async = true;
    sn.noModule = true;
    sn.src = h + s + '.js' + v;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(sn, f);
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://assets.flodesk.com', '/universal', 'fd');
</script>
<script>
  function openModal() {
    window.fd('form', {
      formId: '615edb53f88d548e68f5c863'
    });
  }
</script>
<button onclick="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! The only problem I am having, is that the button will only open the modal once, even after refreshing the page. Is there something in the code which could be causing this? Or that I can add to the code so the button can be pressed again and will still open the popup. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the method `window.fd('form', {formId: '615edb53f88d548e68f5c863'});` would only open the modal once. Have you checked the Flodesk docs?

Comment: Thank you - I'll get in touch with them and see if they can help!